React Select styles not applying in Chrome Extension's Content Script using Shadow DOM and Emotion
I'm developing a Chrome extension and I'm having trouble getting React Select (version 5.8.0) styles to apply correctly in my content script. I'm using Shadow DOM for isolation. After building with a custom webpack configuration, CSS class names are applied to React Select, but the styles are not generated. I can't find them inside the Shadow DOM or anywhere on the webpage where my content script is injected. What's the best way to make CSS-in-JS work in a Chrome extension when using Shadow DOM? I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong during the build process, but unfortunately, I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any suggestions?


//content script js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import PopupManager from './components/popup-manager/popup-manager'
import './index.css'
import LibWrapper from './components/popup-manager/lib-wrapper'
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import createCache from '@emotion/cache'
import Select from 'react-select'

chrome.storage.sync.get(['websites'], (result) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let shadowRoot

    // Create a container for the shadow DOM if it doesn't already exist
    if (!shadowRoot) {
      const shadowContainer = document.createElement('div')
      shadowContainer.id = 'shadow-host'
      document.body.appendChild(shadowContainer)

      // Create a shadow root
      shadowRoot = shadowContainer.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

      // Create a container for React inside the shadow root
      const reactContainer = document.createElement('div')
      shadowRoot.appendChild(reactContainer)

     
      // Create a custom cache for Emotion
      const emotionCache = createCache({
        key: 'css',
        container: shadowRoot,
      })

      // Render React component into the shadow DOM
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(reactContainer)
      root.render(
        <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
          <div id='popup-wrapper'>
            <Select
              options={[
                { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
                { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
                { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
              ]}
            />
          </div>
        </CacheProvider>
      )
    }
  }, 1000)
})



//webpack config overrides file


const paths = require('react-scripts/config/paths')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

// Export override function(s) via object
module.exports = {
  webpack: override,
  // You may also override the Jest config (used for tests) by adding property with 'jest' name below. See react-app-rewired library's docs for details
}

// Function to override the CRA webpack config
function override(config, env) {
  // Replace single entry point in the config with multiple ones
  // Note: you may remove any property below except "popup" to exclude respective entry point from compilation
  config.entry = {
    popup: paths.appIndexJs,
    // options: paths.appSrc + '/options.js',
    background: paths.appSrc + '/background.js',
    content: paths.appSrc + '/content.js',
  }
  // Change output filename template to get rid of hash there
  config.output.filename = 'static/js/[name].js'
  // Disable built-in SplitChunksPlugin
  config.optimization.splitChunks = {
    cacheGroups: { default: false },
  }
  // Disable runtime chunk addition for each entry point
  config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }]],
        plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
      },
    },
  })

  // Shared minify options to be used in HtmlWebpackPlugin constructor
  const minifyOpts = {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    useShortDoctype: true,
    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    keepClosingSlash: true,
    minifyJS: true,
    minifyCSS: true,
    minifyURLs: true,
  }
  const isEnvProduction = env === 'production'

  // Custom HtmlWebpackPlugin instance for index (popup) page
  const indexHtmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    chunks: ['popup'],
    template: paths.appHtml,
    filename: 'popup.html',
    minify: isEnvProduction && minifyOpts,
  })
  // Replace origin HtmlWebpackPlugin instance in config.plugins with the above one
  config.plugins = replacePlugin(
    config.plugins,
    (name) => /HtmlWebpackPlugin/i.test(name),
    indexHtmlPlugin
  )

  // Extra HtmlWebpackPlugin instance for options page
  // const optionsHtmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  //   inject: true,
  //   chunks: ['options'],
  //   template: paths.appPublic + '/options.html',
  //   filename: 'options.html',
  //   minify: isEnvProduction && minifyOpts,
  // });
  // // Add the above HtmlWebpackPlugin instance into config.plugins
  // // Note: you may remove/comment the next line if you don't need an options page
  // config.plugins.push(optionsHtmlPlugin);

  // Custom ManifestPlugin instance to cast asset-manifest.json back to old plain format
  const manifestPlugin = new (ManifestPlugin.WebpackManifestPlugin || ManifestPlugin)({
    fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
  })
  // Replace origin ManifestPlugin instance in config.plugins with the above one
  config.plugins = replacePlugin(
    config.plugins,
    (name) => /ManifestPlugin/i.test(name),
    manifestPlugin
  )

  // Custom MiniCssExtractPlugin instance to get rid of hash in filename template
  const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'static/css/[name].css',
  })
  // Replace origin MiniCssExtractPlugin instance in config.plugins with the above one
  config.plugins = replacePlugin(
    config.plugins,
    (name) => /MiniCssExtractPlugin/i.test(name),
    miniCssExtractPlugin
  )

  // Remove GenerateSW plugin from config.plugins to disable service worker generation
  config.plugins = replacePlugin(config.plugins, (name) => /GenerateSW/i.test(name))

  return config
}

// Utility function to replace/remove specific plugin in a webpack config
function replacePlugin(plugins, nameMatcher, newPlugin) {
  const i = plugins.findIndex((plugin) => {
    return plugin.constructor && plugin.constructor.name && nameMatcher(plugin.constructor.name)
  })
  return i > -1
    ? plugins
        .slice(0, i)
        .concat(newPlugin || [])
        .concat(plugins.slice(i + 1))
    : plugins
}



